# How are trinomial coefficients connected to Pascal’s tetrahedron?

Tags: combinatorics

Using the formula of binomial expansion, we can derive the formula of trinomial expansion:
$$
\begin{align}
\\\left(a+b+c\right)^{n}&=\sum_{r=0}^{n}{n \choose r}a^{n-r}\left(b+c\right)^{r}
\\&=\sum_{r=0}^{n}{n \choose r}a^{n-r}\sum_{s=0}^{r}{r \choose s}b^{r-s}c^{s}
\\&=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\sum_{s=0}^{r}{n \choose r}{r \choose s}a^{n-r}b^{r-s}c^{s}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, ${n \choose r}{r \choose s}$ represents our trinomial coefficient.

As per [Pascal’s triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), there is a recursive definition for the binomial coefficients:
$$
\\{n \choose 0}={n \choose n}=1
\\{n \choose r}+{n \choose r+1}={n+1 \choose r+1}
$$
There is also a [tetrahedral version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_pyramid) where every term is the sum of the adjacent terms on the layer above.

Just like how the row of length $n+1$ of Pascal’s triangle gives us the coefficients for $\left(a+b\right)^{n}$, the layer with side length $n+1$ on this tetrahedron contains the coefficients of $\left(a+b+c\right)^{n}$ and hence:
$$
\\{n \choose r}{r \choose s}+{n \choose r}{r \choose s+1}+{n \choose r+1}{r+1 \choose s+1}={n+1 \choose r+1}{r+1 \choose s+1}
$$
Why is this always the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the recurrence for Pascal's triangle, you can prove the recurrence for Pascal's tetrahedron.
$$
\begin{align}
\color{blue}{\binom{n+1}{r+1}}\binom{r+1}{s+1}
&=\left[\color{blue}{\binom{n}{r+1}}+\color{blue}{\binom{n}{r}}\right]\binom{r+1}{s+1}
\\
&=\binom{n}{r+1}\binom{r+1}{s+1}+\binom{n}{r}\color{green}{\binom{r+1}{s+1}}
\\
&=\binom{n}{r+1}\binom{r+1}{s+1}+\binom{n}{r}\left[\color{green}{\binom rs}+\color{green}{\binom r{s+1}}\right]
\\
&=\binom{n}{r+1}\binom{r+1}{s+1}+\binom{n}{r}\binom rs+\binom{n}{r}\binom r{s+1}. \tag*{$\square$}
\end{align}
$$